# Asp.net core mvc error handling - how to display message prompt when throwing custom exception?

Tags: javascript, c#, error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc, custom-error-handling

Is there anyway to direct custom exception from server side to be shown as prompt dialog in frontend?

I am using c# on backend code.

I tried to implement server-side global exception handling mechanism but to no avail.

Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't very clear. You need to provide more specific information about exactly what you are trying to do. Your non-working global exception handling might even be useful, even if it doesn't work, to illustrate the ideas you are trying to implement. Also really need to know what kind of "server" and "client" you are using - blazor, mvc, razor pages, backend api + react, etc. etc. etc. You tagged `javascript` but I don't think you can run javascript on the server to raise a prompt on the client. I think you might need to say more about this custom exception as well - why is it special?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using asp.net core mvc.

Here's what I wanted to happen. For example, in my service, I have custom prompthelper that throws an exception:

PromptHelper.PromptError($"Document {id} not found.");

public static class PromptHelper
    {
        public static string PromptError(string message) 
        { 
            throw new UserErrorException(message);
        }
    }

Comment: When I throw this exception, what I want is to display a user message prompt on the front-end side without redirecting the page or going to generic error page.

Comment: Is it an API call or form submission? I agree with @topsail you have to update question with those details.

Comment: It is a form submission.